# Using Twitter for registration and authentication from Java web app

Tags: java, oauth, twitter-oauth, scribe

I want to allow users to sign up and login to my Java web app using their Twitter account. The only information I need from their Twitter account is their name (or Twitter username if a name has not been provided) and their email address.

I came across the [scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java) OAuth library that provides [an example](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/cf9c4be00c2142fbfed6735d7d109bb2e90e4af6/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/TwitterExample.java) of how to use it to authenticate with Twitter from a console app. However, I can't figure out how to adapt this to a web app. I don't think I can use this example "as is" because it contains code like:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

that won't work from a webapp. Also, I can't see how to retrieve the user's name and email address once the authentication has completed.

If someone could point me towards a complete example of how to authenticate with Twitter (using OAuth) from a Java webapp and retrieve the user's name and email, that would be great. The example doesn't necessarily have to use scribe, though the less code I have to write myself, the better.

Comment: I don't know that library, but the API call to get user details once you have an access token is [verify_credentials](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/account/verify_credentials). Doesn't appear to contain user email, though. I'd guess you can't get that from Twitter - presumably they expect you to tweet them instead!

Comment: Scanner - the example is using that to accept text input for the authorisation callback. Instead you should specify a callback URL - see the Facebook example instead - which will receive this value from the Twitter auth mechanism.

Comment: I would suggest you ask for the email address anyway in the registration. If you can get the email address from the Twitter API then you can fill the email address field for them but you should still allow user to change it. Some people use different email addresses for different services. For example I could have  myaccount+twitter@gmail.com as my address for twitter, but in your service I would want it to be myaccount+yourservice@gmail.com for filtering purposes

Comment: you might find [this tutorial](http://www.java-only.com/LoadTutorial.javaonly?id=38) helpful :)

Comment: Looks perfect, any idea how I get the email once authorisation has completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an endpoint in you application that receives the `verifier`.

If you go the OOB way, like in the example, the client will have to perform the call to your endpoint manually:

```
curl http://example.com?verifier=123456
```

If you use `callback` like this:

```
Service service = new ServiceBuilder().callback("http://example.com"). //rest of the config
```

Twiiter will perform the call itself and redirect the user browser to your endpoint.